# How do i search within views results?

Tags: views, search

Consider i have a view which filter some Content Type according to a specific field.

I want to place a search box in the view page so the results of the view can be search able.

Is there a module? Or can i somehow do it with search api any tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not called search, it will be called filtering.

Goto your view and add a filter.

[image]

And then select the expose option in the filter.

[image]